# How to replace return carriage in json string made from mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I got stuck with the nuance:

```
//1 - get mysql results into array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    array_push($my_array, $row['fruit_name']);

}

//2 - sort array
sort($my_array);

//3 - convert array to json
json_encode($my_array);
```

OUTPUT:

> ['banana\r', 'apple\r', 'orange\r']

I have tried to remove `\r` with `str_replace("\r", "", $my_array)`, but to no avail.
It seems `str_replace` does not work for any replace at all

Thanks!

Comment: What is your input? Please write in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to escape twice

```
str_replace("\\r", "", $my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `str_replace` in proper manner.

In PHP, if you need to match literal backslash, then you need to use 4 backslashes together.

Try this:

`$json = json_encode($my_array);`

`str_replace("\\\\r", "", $json);`

Comment: Strange. i have a working code where, 4 backslashes are working and 2 are not.  `["banana", "apple", "orange"]` This is what I get after using 4 backslashes. After 2 backslashes I get this `["banana\","apple\","orange\"]`

Comment: It might be just my php configuration or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sort(str_replace("\\r", "", $my_array));

str_replace("\\\\r", "", $json);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider removing carriage return before array_push. Adding it with carriage return and then removing it is not logical.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   array_push($my_array, str_replace("\r", '', $row['fruit_name']));
}

//2 - sort array
sort($my_array);

//3 - convert array to json
json_encode($my_array);
```

**Sample code**

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "xxx\r",
    "yyy\r"
);

echo json_encode($array) . "\n";

array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key){
    $item = str_replace("\r", '', $item);
});

echo json_encode($array) . "\n";
?>
```

**Result**

```
["xxx\r","yyy\r"]
["xxx","yyy"]
```